# Batch Rendering and how I should go about it

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I have an iOS 2D rendering engine capable of rendering individual frames from a spritesheet/ texture atlas. However, it does this by cutting the spritesheet into a different texture for each frame. As you can guess, when animating this is INCREDIBLY slow even when drawing only one entity per frame as glBindTexture is called every frame.

So I have changed it so that it keeps the spritesheet in one piece and simply clips the spritesheet texture to the desired frame at run-time. Here is a piece of sample code that I intend to modify slightly but has the general desired effect i'm looking for.

```
- (void) drawInRect:(CGRect)dest withClip:(CGRect)src withRotation:(CGFloat)rotation {
GLfloat 
    gx0 = src.origin.x/_width, gx1 = (src.origin.x+src.size.width)/_width,
    gy0 = src.origin.y/_height, gy1 = (src.origin.y+src.size.height)/_height;
GLfloat     coordinates[] = { 
    gx0,    gy1,
    gx1,    gy1,
    gx0,    gy0,
    gx1,    gy0 
};
GLfloat vertices[] = {  
    -dest.size.width/2,     -dest.size.height/2,    0.0,
    dest.size.width/2,      -dest.size.height/2,    0.0,
    -dest.size.width/2,     dest.size.height/2,     0.0,
    dest.size.width/2,      dest.size.height/2,     0.0 
};

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _name);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(dest.origin.x+dest.size.width/2, dest.origin.y+dest.size.height/2, 0);
glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1); //in degrees, about screen origin.
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
glPopMatrix();
}
```

However I would like to edit this so that I could load an array in with multiple different clipping rectangles (for occasions such as wanting to draw multiple items from one spritesheet). However from what I understand if I simply loaded in more triangles into the vertices Array and starting sticking in more rectangular coordinates into the coordinates array, wouldn't that cause some nasty texture-stretching in the space between the different triangles that the textures were bound to.
 If so is there even a way for me to batch render multiple frames from the same spritesheet to different parts of the screen?

I understand if my desired outcome is not entirely clear. Let me know if you need me to elaborate on anything and I'll gladly do my best to better-explain.
Thank you.

Comment: "However, it does this by cutting the spritesheet into a different texture for each frame." Then it's not actually pulling things from a texture atlas, is it?

Comment: well, textureatlas.png goes in and frames come out. However that was the old way which i've now scrapped. The new way im trying to devise is described above.

Comment: You might want to disambiguate your use of the word "frame". Most people understand this to mean a complete scene rendering (e.g.: frames-per-second, etc). What you seem to be describing would ordinarily be called a sprite (hence spritesheet).

Comment: ahhhhh my apologies. I did indeed mean it to be sprite.

Comment: I play alot of Street Fighter and "frame" is a much more natural word for it to me, but you're right most would say sprite :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object with batched rendering is to get as much data in to opengl as possible in as few calls as possible. Using this as your guiding principle, steps you can take to increase batching efficiency are:

1. Use a spritesheet to reduce texture binds - texture binds are comparatively expensive, so it's really important to minimise them.
2. Don't draw your sprites one-at-a-time - batch up the geometry into one big VBO and draw it all at once. This means that:

   - you won't be able to use GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, as your sprites won't all be contiguous on the screen, try rendering an indexed buffer with GL_TRIANGLES.
   - you won't be able to use glTranslate, etc - you'll have to do the math yourself

Comment: Thank you. I think switching to GL_TRIANGLES is key to my query. However, for example my player character has a spritesheet all to herself, that is absolutely full. 1024x1024. Does this not mean that I can only render her by herself. As I cannot really concatonate her sheet with any others as some devices don't support textures above that size, therefore rebinding textures is unavoidable to draw anything that isn't on the main character spritesheet? I'm sure i could create VBO's large enough to blanket the planet but the moment ...

Comment: I have to get something from another spritesheet, I'd have to take the performance hit of binding a new texture. Is this an unavoidable overhead or am I missing a trick?

Comment: Fundamentally yeah, if you have to draw something from another sheet there's no way to avoid the hit. Just try to draw as many things from a given sheet as possible while it is bound.

Comment: Cool thanks, I'm gonna give this a shot, see if my game speeds up.